# Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?

Tags: android-studio

I recently upgraded from Eclipse to Android Studio and I'm not really liking the experience. I'm comparing them both on a **Windows 7 64 bit ultimate** with **16GB** of ram and **Intel i7 4770** running NVidia Geforce 780 with the latest NVidia drivers if it matters and I'm running the latest JDK and the latest Android Studio.

The Android Studio is very slow in building the project which I can live with but it's also extremely resource intensive and sometimes slows down the PC to a crawl.

Whenever I'm building or running anything in AS, my PC seems to become extremely sluggish. It also causes flickering of screen and occasionally blanking my second monitor if I click on "Gradle build running" spinner which I find very odd. The RAM usage also shoots up to ~3GB which I find excessive for doing nothing (this is when it's idle after a few builds).

In addition, the panels at the bottom of AS keep jumping around which is a horrible user experience (moves from `Android` to `Messages` to `Version Control` or anything else on an ad-hoc basis depending on what's happening which is very, very annoying).

What I would like to know is basically:

1) How do I make Android Studio run better? I may be doing something wrong or missing some updates that I'm not aware of and I'm sure others have also noticed these behaviors and have found some solutions to it.

2) How do I "pin" the bottom panels so that they don't jump around and instead, let me, the user, navigate to them when I wish to instead of automatically switching them?

Many thanks and my apologies again if it's not the correct place for these questions.

**Edit 1**
Some more comments:

- I'm using the latest `stable` build as of today. The build is `Android Studio 1.2.2 Build # AI-141.1980579, Build on June 3, 2015`
- The behavior happens when using either Java 7 or 8. It doesn't appear to be related to the version of Java.
- I am not using Presentation Mode. Just the vanilla view.
- Doing the changes to the build configuration (thanks to @Blackbelt and his answer) appears to have helped with the build but the other problems with sluggishness and general user experience remain.

Comment: I personally stopped using Android Studio around September, it received some strange update that made it so heavy and I don't understand why. I kept using it for some months because I didn't really know what else to do, a professor of mine convinced me to try building the project from the terminal (linux) and it was the best choice ever! I write my files using my favorite text editor and the project builds in 5-10 seconds max.

Comment: Do not use the latest version of Android Studio. Only use the version that comes from the Stable channel. It doesn't always use the Stable channel by default. Do not use the latest OracleJDK. Use only the officially supported JDK for Android, which is the OpenJDK 7, not 8 (in theory, 8 should work, but I assume there is a reason Google says it only supports 6 or 7). And yes, you read that right, Google switched things around. Before it was the OpenJDK that you were not supposed to use, but now it's the reverse. Oracle is out. OpenJDK is in.

Comment: And the jumping around might be because you're in presentation mode. Turn that off by going to the menu View > Presentation Mode

Comment: @StephanBranczyk where did you read that? Official page (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) still says oracle jdk.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thank you for your comments. I'm using the latest `stable` build and I had the same issue before using the Java 7 which is why I upgraded to Java 8 hoping it would fix the problem. I'll add this as an update to my post. I'm also not using `Presentation Mode` so that couldn't be it.

Comment: Need to fire that guy who oversees android studio @google. My PC literally crwals right now. My mouse pointer jumps. Its extremely frustrating to use android studio. It used to be better before

Comment: android studio is not heavy. if anything, gradle build is slow. I use it everyday without any slow down on a 2 years old laptop with 4Gb (but then again, only under linux, so windows may be the cause)

Comment: Try disbling any antivirus software and see if that helps. Android Studio is reading and writing files all the time.

Comment: Okay. I will agree that every answer written above will somehow help the cause. I am one of those who is on the same boat. With nothing working my way, and Android Studio refusing to build on the Offline mode due to the associated dependencies, I did something that eased my problem within minutes. Every time I build the gradle, I turn off my internet. ( Notice that the Offline mode is not checked). I don't know how and why but this works.

Comment: horrible ... I am new with java/android/AS ... I am following the `http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html` .... I started on monday ... today is saturday ... I have barely written 30 lines of code ... gradle takes so many minutes to do anything/everything ... errors constantly that require 'invalidating cache', which requires a 12 minute re-start ... I have been programming for 15 years ... true I am on an old machine (I like my winxp) ... maybe that's the problem

Comment: I agree with the other posters here, I've given Android Studio a fair crack of the whip for the past few weeks on various high-spec machines, and found it to be a thoroughly demoralizing exercise.  Anything that takes that amount of time to do even the simplest of tasks has got a fatal design flaw, to put it mildly.  Absolute waste of time.

Comment: I found Android studio is run slight faster, more stable in Linux based OS, such as Ubuntu. I switched between Windows and Ubuntu, using the same Android studio and Genymotion. They working well in Ubuntu but slagging in Windows.

Comment: Horrified by AS, my notebook sometime stands still for over 10 seconds. I have developed all kinds of applications with a lot of IDE, VS.NET, Netbeans, Eclipse, Code::Block, sublime, etc. AS is the worst, how could they make IDE that slow and laggy.

Comment: I am seriously considering to quit Android programming after 5 wonderful years with eclipse..all because of Andriod Studio. How can google be so dumb?

Comment: on Mac OSX is slow too. Sure was better in Eclipse with Android SDK

Comment: On Windows please watch your antivirus once as it interferes with the build process, I stopped using Chrome and uninstall Avast antivirus, it dramatically increased the build performance

Answer (score 304):

to sum it up

1) in AndroidStudio's `settings > compile` enable checkbox named `Compile independent modules in parallel`.

2) Under `Help> Edit Custom VM Options` I have:

```
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

P.S. - Some people say Note, instead of    VM options, it's better to combine can be overriden by combining those lines into one line single command in gradle.properties, like this :

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m ......

3) I have an old dual core with 4GB ram, running ubuntu. Qs command line option I have only `--offline` (which specifies that the build should operate without accessing network resources). I also enabled the remaining checkboxes and now it's running ok:

- Make project automatically
- Use in-process building Configure on demand
- Check the AndroidStudio's settings, under compile that the checkbox `Compile independent modules in parallel` is enabled.

Under Vmoptions I have

```
-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024
```

I have an old dual core with 4GB ram, running ubuntu. Qs commandline option I have only `--offline` , which specifies that the build should operate without accessing network resources. I enabled also the remaining checkboxes:

1. Make project automatically
2. Use in-process building
3. Configure on demand

   and it is running ok

**Edit**

It is possible to provide additional options through `studio.vmoptions` located at (just replace X.X with version):

- **Windows**: go to `%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudioX.X\studio.exe.vmoptions`   (or `studio64.exe.vmoptions`)
- **Mac**: `~/Library/Preferences/.AndroidStudioX.X/studio.vmoptions`
- **Linux**: `~/.AndroidStudioX.X/studio.vmoptions` (and/or `studio64.vmoptions`)

Increasing the value of `-Xmx` should help a lot. E.g

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

will assign 4G as max heap, with initial value of 1G

**Edit**:

On windows the defaults are stored into  `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\*.vmoptions`. The IDE allows you to tweak those values through `Help->Edit Custom VM options` (thanks to `@Code-Read` for pointing it out).

**EDIT 2**:

Android studio 3.5 makes easier to change same of those values. Just go to:

```
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That may help with the build performance which is the area I am less concerned with to be perfectly honest. I'm much more concerned about the actual IDE being extremely sluggish, causing a lot of slow down of the PC and its behavior of moving the bottom panels automatically than the build to be honest but nevertheless, these are very helpful and I'll apply them.

Comment: the ide itself shouldn't be much more heavy than Eclipse. Try applying those settings, and check if it does make any difference

Comment: @Blackbelt Updated my question. Unfortunately the problem with the IDE remain. The experience is orders of magnitude worse than using Eclipse (and that's saying something!)

Comment: that's very strange. I had a similar issue on my working machine on Mac os. After 20 minutes of UI was unusable, but those settings did the track for me. I found a ticket on the Android bug track ([here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66096)). Maybe you should fill up a new one giving them the whole picture of your issues

Comment: I don't know if the in the meanwhile you fixed that. If you don't you can try something else. Look for `studio.exe.vmoptions` or `studio64.exe.vmoptions` and change the values of `-Xms` and `-Xmx` and restart the ide

Comment: Will this setting affect Spring if we were to run Gradle / Spring project on it?

Comment: even now is 2015 AS is still heavy and slow

Comment: yes, Android Studio is horribly slow. It I did everything mentioned here, and it is still close to unusable. Actually I consider to ditch it and try Eclipse instead. Real frustration.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - My vmoption files were in android-studio/bin

Comment: I am so lost in your path navigation tbh. The files you mentioned doesn't exist on my machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: what machine do you have ? I would recommend to check the documentation tho. Google likes to change the path of these files.

Comment: The easiest way I found to change the vmoptions on the said directories (as of ASv2.1.2) is go to Help > Change Custom VM Options. Though it warns you not to change it, I highly suggest to keep a copy of it somewhere in your computer.

Comment: I've just turn Android studio into Notepad, I disable almost all live templates, code templates, almost plugins, inspections (only XML layout inspections are on). But I rejected commiting suicide in my room now.

Comment: Defaults for VM options are currently stored at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\*.vmoptions`.  Don't edit this file, but it's useful as a reference when editing the file created by ***Help->Edit Custom VM options***.

Comment: This is way too awesome! I got my build running from average 35 seconds to average 4 seconds

Comment: In the newer studio 1st point is reached through Settings>Build,execution, deployment>Compiler>Compile independent modules(check box)

Comment: I  got Android studio Failed to create jvm error -6. But then I removed the file %USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudioX.X\studio.exe.vmoptions (or studio64.exe.vmoptions. And it launches again. Then I put -Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops   and seems now its fine with speed.

Comment: If Android Studio won't launch after editing `studio.vmoptions`: move `# <------ increase this to most of your RAM` to its own line (at least on Mac).  Also, here is the original location and settings on my machine:
`~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0/studio.vmoptions`
`-Xms256m`
`-Xmx5120m`
`-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m`
`-XX:+UseCompressedOops`

Comment: If you are using 64bit Android Studio, you should change "studio64.exe.vmoptions". Also, if you are increasing max ram to > 4gb, you have to make sure your 64bit Android Studio is using the 64bit JRE

Comment: No 2 above...does it same as File->Setting->"Build,Execution,Deployment"->Compiler->Android Compiler->Additional VM Options?

Comment: On mac, be careful about adding the line -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM . Pound Sign # Comment seems to crash Android Studio and you can't relaunch it! Get rid of the # to fix

Comment: Starting from Android Studio 3.5, some of the settings mentioned above can be set in Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up/57588861#57588861).

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks a million, man. My computer went from crashing and not being able to complete a simple build to actually working pretty fast with Android Studio. I really appreciate it.

Comment: # <------ increase this to 

this line crashed my Windows Android Studio as well @ZackMorris

Comment: @im_chc make sure your 64bit Android Studio is using the 64bit JRE

why? how ? Thx 

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander First of all, you should check the jre you installed is 64bit; but most of the cases, it is that multiple JREs with different "bitness" are installed at the same time, the challenge is to check which JRE is the java app/android studio is run against (should be checking the PATH environment variable if I'm not mistaken), also you need to research how to list the existing installed JREs (I think it is checking the registry, you need to Google it)

Comment: Apparently the comment `# <------ increase this to most of your RAM ` crashed on Android Studio, oh and also please remove the unnecessary whitespace for the options; my `vim` plugin detected this.

Comment: did this and some of the other tips on here and it would not launch anymore so going for a fresh install

Comment: the jvm config file becomes corrupted, one of the configuration settings are no longer supported, the directory path to navigate to is incorrect in the error provided from android studio, similarly uninstalling android studio seems like a solution

Comment: @den the answer is from 2015. Surely things changed and surely you must able to understand that looking for something more recent might be more relevant

Comment: @Blackbelt surely you don't disqualify methods based on age without first verifying them?

Comment: Your solution broke the program. Windows users don't believe him. He is a Linux user and does not know about Windows. My program now stopped working.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone How did you do that?

Answer (score 64):

Tips to make android studio fast:

**Enable Offline Work:**

1. Click File -> Settings. Search for "gradle" and click in `Offline work` box.
2. Go to Compiler (in same settings dialog just below `Gradle`) and add `--offline` to `Command-line Options` text box.

**Improve Gradle Performance**

gradle can be optimized too. The easy way is to modify the settings in global `gradle.properties` (create it if not exists in the following folders: Windows - `C:\users\your_name\.gradle\`; Linux- `/home/<username>/.gradle/`; Mac- `/Users/<username>/.gradle/`; ) and in that file, add these two lines:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

For More: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html

Comment: It becomes too long while elaborate here. So, I have provided the link. Follow the link there is step by step guide.

Comment: @SajanRana don't post links. links die.

Comment: @SajanRana neither you nor the link you posted elaborate on what exactly `Enable Offline Work` means.

Comment: I agree with @Jin, the answer is correct, but a bit more info is intersting. Here is what I found: 
Offline work : If you check this option, Gradle will use things from the cache itself for dependency resolution. In case the files are not there in the cache, then it will result in a build error.

So by enabling it, gradle will avoid to check online resources, which may make Studio faster, however I still think it is too slow for the rest of the process (other than building).

Answer (score 49):

I detected another reason - **Thumbs.db**, which affected performance badly.

Go to `File > Settings > Editor > File Types` and in field **Ignore files and folders** add this:  `Thumbs.db;`

Now, Android Studio runs like a charm.

Comment: This helps. Can you elaborate why?

Comment: I suppose that AS generates a lot of files, while Windows generates thumbnails for them on the fly.

Comment: Cant find `file types` under the Editor any more.. infact cant find it at all.

Comment: I know it's quite old but found it under `File > Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files`

Comment: got the following error: This function should be called while holding treeLock

Comment: Adding a description to your answer makes it easy for others to know the root cause of the issue and the solution as well.

Comment: Presumably this is a windows only fix...

Answer (score 28):

Adding more memory helped me:

1. Click "Help"
2. Edit Custom VM Options

Android Studio 2.1.2 Edit Custom VM Options:

[image]

3. Change values

like below:

```
-Xms512m    
-Xmx2560m   
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m    
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m    
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

4. Restart Android Studio

Comment: Won' start now. Where are these settings stored? Answer: ~/.AndroidStudio3.0/studio64.vmoptions

Comment: you might face an error wile relaunching. youll need to delete the file and this solution wont help you

Answer (score 28):

Recommendations:

- **MUST TO SAY**: if you have any chance, spend some money for better PC(cpu), maybe it's most affecting factor ..

Tweaks:

- Some people say, that OS (Operating System) might cause much slowness. For example, XP or LINUX (or etc) was mentioned to perform 70% faster (don't know why..).
- Disable VCS by `File > Settings > Plugins` and disable the following things :
  `CVS Integration`;  `Git Integration`; `GitHub`; `Google Cloud ...` things; `Subversion Integration`; `hg4idea`;
- Editor is a resource eating too (especially on Large Monitors) and slow. Make it much much faster: click `Help > Edit custom VM options` and add these lines :

  `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false`

  `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`

   save it and Restart Android Studio.
- If Android Studio has a proxy server setting and can't reach the server then it takes a long time to build and waiting for a timeout. Removing it helps much. `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System settings > HTTP Proxy`.
- Another Useful quote (from [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb)):

> Modules are expensive… On my current project  I had to build some libraries from scratch and had to fork some that almost fitted my needs but not quite! If that modules are not constantly modified, it’s important to have this into consideration: the time needed to compile them from scratch, or even to check if the previous individual module build is up-to-date, can be up to almost 4x greater than to simply load that dependency as a binary `.jar/.aar`.
>
> Hint: run the `gradle build -profile` for an HTML report showing where
> the time goes regarding the build process.
>
> Note: keep that “unnecessary” modules in your version control system
> for the eventuallity of a quickfix/improvement in that dependency.

- In your Gradle build script, use only 
  specific Google Service, like:   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:...'`
  Instead of full Google Library:  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:...'`
  *(Compile time goes from 2 minutes to around 25 seconds).*
- Gradle configures every project before executing tasks, regardless of whether the project is actually needed for the particular build. In global `gradle.properties` adding this will help much: `org.gradle.configureondemand=true`
- Surprisingly, [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450007/2377343) say , they solved problem by **reducing**: 1) heapsizes to  `-Xmx256m` (instead of higher values);  2) Emulator Ram-size (from `Edit AVD > Advanced Settings`);

## Everyday Recommendations:

- Don't run multiple projects simultaneously.
- Don't close emulator after using once (use same emulator for running app each time;  If you test large apps, better to use a real mobile phone instead of emulator).
- clean your project every time after running your app in emulator - click `Build > Clean Project` (or `Rebuild` ), you can use keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 15):

## An anti-virus is causing the slow-down

In one particular system I looked at, this issue was caused by an over-zealous anti-virus that was interfering with Gradle, the build manager for Android Studio. It seems every time Gradle was "touching" a `.jar` file, the virus checker was unzipping the `.jar` and scanning it for viruses first. The Gradle build could only continue once the unzipping and scan was complete, thus leading to very long build times (5 min plus). Since Android Studio, by default, runs a Gradle build when you start up, it manifests as an extremely slow start-up.

The problem is extremely easy to check for:

1. While you are experiencing the symptoms of a slow Android Studio, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> and open Windows Task Manager.
2. Click on the `Processes` tab to see the active processes and sort by CPU. If you see an anti-virus taking significant amounts of CPU percentage intermittently while Android Studio appears to be loading, it is likely to be the same issue.
3. You can verify further by looking at the scan logs of the anti-virus to see if it is indeed, examining the `.jar` files.

To solve this, you will have to add the correct directories to the "excluded folders" of your anti-virus. Assume that your Windows username is "Username" and you have installed Android Studio on `C:` drive. You would then request to exclude from the virus check the following directories:

```
C:\Users\Username\.android
C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio2.2
C:\Users\Username\.gradle
C:\Users\Username\.m2
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Please note that you may need to take additional security precautions if you exclude these directories and you should co-operate with your security department in the workplace. This may involve setting up your own Maven repository if deemed necessary.

(I am aware that this is a late answer, but none of the previous answers have addressed this potential issue)

Comment: I Also added android studio installation folder, java folder, my project folder, and some .exe files as process in windows defender.

Comment: This also solves a problem with the emulator I have been suffering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623384/emulator-from-android-studio-starts-thinking-every-few-seconds-and-doesnt-let Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Starting from Android Studio 3.5 some of the settings can be configured via:

**Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings**

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Are you saying we should increase the IDE max heap size?

Answer (score 11):

The best way to boost up android studio runtime performance is to use **SSD Drive**. It will boost the performance as very much. I did all the above things and felt I should go for new laptop, but suddenly I came to know about SSD Drive and I tried it. Its Much Much better.....

Comment: also if you have any antivirus installed try stopping it while running android studio. it will again boost your speed.

Comment: An SSD isn't cheap. But that's an ok solution.

Comment: Even using an M2 with 32GB RAM and AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8 core, Android Studio runs slowly

Comment: yes that's why I used SSD and it is performing well.

Answer (score 7):

As you are learning, ***performance problems with AS are not trivial to diagnose!***  In my case, an array of 9215-character-long strings (see below) was causing AS to dump threads every time I typed a few characters.  The thread dump in turn caused AS to freeze for many seconds at a time.  This bug appeared in the Windows 64 bit release of AS 2.2, still occurs in 2.2.1, but was not present in 2.1.

Finding out that long strings were causing my lockups involved a lot of trial and error.  But, I learned a lot in the process, ***to wit***:

- `idea.log` contains excellent diagnostics (Help->Show Log in Explorer);
- If you see extreme, but intermittent slowdowns, suspect AS is dumping threads.  This will be reported in `idea.log`.  If threads are being dumped, the dumps will tell what code AS was executing when the problem occurred;
- Find out whether the problem occurs in other projects.  ***If not***:

  - Look for unusual content in the project file you are editing when it happens (atypical indentation, long lines, overall size, special characters, etc.);
  - Try exporting settings from another project (File->Export Settings) and importing them to the problem project (File->Import Settings);
- ***If so***:

  - If threads were dumped, consult these and text in `idea.log` near in time to the dump notices for details;
  - Consult `idea.log` for messages about memory consumption and see other answers to this question such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/30818099/5025060 for advice regarding memory and other tunables.

BTW, for the present I have worked around the problem I describe above by moving my long strings into a separate file (a new class containing only the array itself).  I try not to edit this file with AS:

```
package com.code_read.numerous;

// Stored in this separate file as workaround for but in Android Studio 2.2 and 2.2.1:
public class numstrings {

    // Array of long random numbers, pregenerated to save CPU:
    public static String[] numStrings = {

        "199480174700500684371420190688025369652294974898532667703870978918596743889034133861151427235088532762252190859715724937087994424214079133514743202613482472074004942240108422672013308512961698346232617905052490578458131173818163968088306365788124935229987389963310288307926351857183977760191417618209693717342383094977491190187330292385653783886145924147263878165609860155555740880616076742235066585775525946974068428032859462348789185664980466131158481988902160769240355605036247170008906461173632371674336904556655004329788696238223897234680357492949394186524384271378442506571046125386240017147676374848515226581822322873860294758364671523301932707269219884364668888296719810681914252024967226535139980038835402500469293303445385631066898382763993166693693891600944079638681397398367264401490441377833191085876891792887328136898520902148268395208138632765905189182445119192547131981262125997953230672094440970962973597034366673186995403431640556509145661772208699764304562424356210879969147034091389350776774099307413678640772848528929610792920689008507739250708291284695239814666712127874431690342513485124398592905398339314701750560443486724884409641301581250356812598254397195582041374207050524854721410717517826514256884605932903495291614152958393041446721244450203654252461792454977205340965473442168314446921087589856268559622056019215736207512553225494282253374340892190892964167854464270350359407498074340634452159050304590622713766142827196013111327741833914397311108235022871374679837822251636256816946000031801632697665029388147643065534169657637935011864906687144383247248575867393905547656023089908356955316327699678982262881769783281879024192545078595861099291383574264862512114130067137999586421949009586778213657551456231235508255794338865353976867429772427179918460616316131342501970048444481906603539188074631511252603708953524733006893213588956114050791560328718558587163598674421588217380809694917621993988723888733472235367656543521907102504160836734526706672672061129158228943943961208967494809881423654493768539990181950253198622321856894324399743506614313017879100091908634564608851227240409514256964261431166731255216249943382663958593911252365390104901951019163641553646386915867844316868296886856122097683605632869023634580949922723527949383421859260253787750248640586488155271705354318971930705305681639438500545630794869976987809742158447119320670554178634632109983849140691164486258482922700124353388939055409126960673867435504694534537972989184927497251539970824341488149544927174416431338978095499553363866217528144380339413096788582745229165179013109746529904790441634036324656629258183244396216977736609176927617841924291304236306725585481004526207256126249788205441106740479328308566203633303785210558827801926199279334869844921970247706896704588537079433072095445424535530854095822282531649200446125855450924096198151719358284629425483620333602513734130440802599571444639236468727586327901486711828547798932589324730675183636768495336889434743116373841074286121127947547754103882500005968494120728533889301116500651387720411937760371686364320729394390169544403796948255139588769868997312588780450158790560760093773180833497054203906896463690321778617639560964637561984865448197089236779186045120326461271783320113343686490407274805637853745997098574967843535555214227806718213323236579240122449595189776026857194861192260435592237583754498777823878919462358453553525468074152734416933788261651160608911358193365205774610833712659270259537468997175675611106769471773639491122956114410572271964037496252046002633139033229094067102926662843014688243495810764107876347939515840933639293755383642974182862980342270078605141586386956993823477302317789808723114028287869904362158728685338534454353886384668017657582003089836977765285161563767051590888534730491047324356587246491873963645331147759110815548406659559086623742565689131160816873078928719150806816828094339118862380985774989197433606765766698179872216924780614351925493388103444249169463919616530661916366867058921827320239545671233921815306937959970928487769990744894323260198942599949511829120527153889470305293747421875929597907863004936662249162616863538907259383989683557351124864962027711188603419729221915037041631423186559909007303718063435208812948660284585114603102538597611757387763679988962831024468515792778125928449962458120436831348703819770498415146367232423575963346662334586696284187440935738671265597243626878590482688540466283239505795285203222312952727768986993054183353764623988975079536152274635683995523743740674237109205318984477845559143807318533592235565607859418218764426920445870800448778289651837205082867361097390372276842811160616927570980788319948404234156903914893965657104289589790051123586608292524558595741415545621155770330883498473838958946706678756502460255029859500858857950640229689701775631558304956149273122701277512634671602844059638169586254728659407967362269959105419218416567093118243957542316274295498328248817394832630466984581744392334983388346309080227929827437548742182906915518737736211928504845091782481456286893146781544794159295091551690979113667607106910341688300199029887449503700494407767038172311101451145387305383586418395623858905393669579043267868910063346375438826548689323643777791563205248979849233001328183147648563739211128790317882512942976057274763094369736846067104652467759155731666690210808042980939553702716431018458310300829399315635070328956543394251955663239488509275645610557061416837507256175426220804774390422080366850103219147627475492147311993091462233708107815399346519610636302312501953470382656988296844245456380956448418706248790737380938971901188740142511500064909417579265118558940349387209436071467447553322059300256060882213572671888633311468806647866886714364480390741971261155146966455235245469216037781902665760552750139630086762191170698020993656670315633268514333717896691033913231320046383254246489147334950779602143851763331162696957861920662919779275597627512142784352182141445813314700768143243068609858396666573299094606418264269814358631471099430351875376096756985414279698633021999241922359616560734207061899223922960812283262525756913341822754012297564666186625578304476940819388933133524627367540790564522544564778697253990225087539167235818088172467629494330066609424362165903452686384032519162803665396381708558770446760515949895545741296290000569932285497599817855761012405729639826090606199167309178353879552491532632275280392848742608582274239730529782945165478328337271868836845191541561507500208302765174521037399945168283511465921684324919886458514198917808605615454461104693224591355736463666638896809273773847099278335819353734646745529499084220949854110923079439768551794882440443420790356174953271799037409969510616472239791991169317996129581919960609015888209147433981232988872613046167259127350908379785462051364248739967784342740440741101122829282932814615147660486375475931239052842925639656692838804305210923978980395884616464432067372256203421577994958229803819990849889517637605263836801607526144871336189683467963044999507242077754258044251900402909622687958520423101104141436068489671206919737260688257054648581817294964263976562185927570807911388018018258993650653884478612449747409649857255718750594340185450229237142106113706239341772394393537650157754917387723238567597362916800367131878174394802843379112357851740285545973436469806324934485196633484429168467828668601262966377703119558087801302745104185528840638941125570169525964145077815381271805810720809495436404303742978449708284706732193106170741321000772555673307985656286163852732962806975120835420863932323287224469231389811257137937311964638921084917958805713020592860162667905063938602685993936855490751349046724756605329409781900459600797487634904548282818720869599606861780977530250890161804971763916627465964744221537291053168212191636434331558216175364205277673887186837423218242958128611987999992758177897869145149526733124420365122337894731881057516805213861310033107963352309585687684446050606840221227910822989213514546762603795082253295181456389080556377952947742314716657931379603906644497934747404742170445520704889248852909123050926587050705346518656114252388410901469887789781852617252193018440532227714049598132339736764081531406292297426695168307774532183927565674228199289403241512915778463699914633503875989705880500660094881980955882992903315688284154677620736795450367750443201591100620839868814285991917187047458820949842767861309178482708477168470785039327561836424824805811165820104246196555794331332996669674045783102109040643272357674713449239668592816891229724897439143640828454023115418378970208060898790311768852380590403898569796811536628763765619516959616465670971025029199700641157243991360225331144567474481980740980668474128099060992445134897801758103355434948807029912167490453622803119627912623581848536805420633517354236148799130118992602264832753012209719060145941443653691895443984877692560563086567054695734773175413167885599427596673930470696429105758701992261543691172194016438106532173687638780672882677814493551318364786071441551104902517495593342110486408028970990714051385299637116595208818449861724282758368826773373374959971277798785804077474187828568828476934339459420148793412883150",
        "538224164506517727168379814270004264954262890967803652129634085563292029281605229340786265842963091265375081322656426327691825397596305139095807229239401766181924729149454472921237119900736562299208507666998730548950184609967143155404571139681858767360957532407547767766581682749533474070778066308353055041737658281319225985623143723322979093908077261749579698949722143844865215753260704863233251983739190238438585852441601269285486958770074555894548287326458992187454462079069306138536753824858451724299502671847412359542456725524317603333127725189754333904127835917709082397117314374344841098649440198952614890746624715994850686377293277867933955487391617475414663233091117706057717653437506940130690492779072621106571276835896964128477419355461824833007422652722892089498401815585650339262735314718997015721760285362989670501888405449175944105348564991465379865502815442568994217413701289990025169571135430868678513387334362169047349385097189952383252809797239281560886730670313602788309858480241742834539376684722791418327801153139657791555902866428852378920616927209513842521394245291956399576801110297424150355942220383127708823635328491162642528500795465164461339897320905999182040888049657238854537216919531949022496815649153550998615631758342112481970649311069999931374418401873433024214179662539540883626504860812401222013654614884183265556578861843196602514379747643437577278486455637659461692515650033708286255995750664532809105614477191900536646989973294380911406440123202917020543294608335869356083501814588100186652356940293410193583108936507174010508730547579479594424713594002615307062956405060637859223904493241124826364582313371226790237755829730863075824362871968331865676368450061869716192958213846294980005144665140729523705625975650250913572426639956129293774660716629920750249524030812360814423275145704510305475471599108987851917139525934434155829774559599984930365268286061310405222779602887256748903477260217130747213255028270120814131477184214466827946467189929171109471222122321781698513717077961138680899475230521104220021956144708736321339718012605885629667271185753633589711538217011780317199309005150619910226290258606968201034831451279285351626936018493376731628135398444826695563731645399766722832213714326969977166479301504241269743154952405125518862249585946211635202670206079658236138581470119927833603919638673595466193694285521696174533703023847425191146225399211910859996212735505434202471982673116410979955302943872996222782251188889797453222122118340601140765762050865117038651251924809853248767149255310571487174953189406262461045337548275503362245324296778392145673240872161212904525195326091442868284645515492949181928962102650369388016101486909636578309464736085550719873530004572608218612771334204843378797447816965534882619866758953492744624542308949271562610878902677734983794103655386943014200382950775896136847248170152492053814891464245663515427967344370332218795309066345645753963683675310959651463186934113877748975354804724385336161212461668326293653878197970705660956307781435211341258181110817847199795550229343870629183131938496385393103613345446965343702524527285650585793819011062255528783572801384755547339757189973901102728798129755193065859838182563879981780954262005796062637576511231241443434331171809822894324123753165477778469728090079401173957345155941105580762201810708213077226618724235486083102862810041621061166403929820695859415790727065329954170405272420309443687650005312634780559478100510198693442377014278276554921873492874338296974328247512240058483178986970686481429662053321485231172147300032651945090781006753618086127522738639483880490609376294431040414520360826477062101428243729921142508398976634656490798240120553325502856616278098521671075879092501730718808714541228313275254145714018560781459353526353227881612961968793972766897143956572113542916207199147961710145111046554899487126641090524158317439204601922483991169906886478567971798641676381952943035217373454681987587805591011217498046449281585885528147735917241804752657592955740206966021211842392441403708809079502903010500379965582448141804577819122673871443655907443795539672468455979677549431293106288271932050346631500287602175371865943781936540554382984304724097222638329259252009624430698945188473581273102616186096857444455590249553427286857598862389440750330212575200947705079697958418126668654772650001967712891183376253390796458314338083748473931585515921615694157280199091233014626670437265932854816696073747199020367782282750469898234657723303623065763946721350199198124381089295881349043396200116870404706730447453694640127520344108293809433706053279580858859981831981145259642994156115348994153409515332190714496695178066164657038576407330756425651351910143884103008599258982342794361116576254544716333349447388917606521902296446129906799300892625933497927680934057875748488562502583788021088460847542122629532281540915167125712134059011294733193338806665352190898772064079614377396560467361735144910595159196625744894635765414508428182582195935281561176637424688405390881327676886203967634620641490139835786477852859151685333919226211419623843640736490696222368214514608866918660741740478728095699337580878621149576661678523829374300157157278668566218717849777314215124448445257696853651163171851588905845296279139538174221105885455390417634993814515761194372376448867312932698371439509465354789329167336154865083365498571678846394239876288801890960856391974200258201177558423866895944503981197241629075358819018115130381239431357293457670267116618421892520944925953400263676636028993365189377273814879596365094915787821109571143126831231452367431282415243511115547744416422407534808156629306675994132643059500315715827695321955177580261595331150963040058964908997344260596477846100309223669721566222470207499488952252338020599539432718661089801855181342526438803473636154594287887641549215962248635916039475197945009663236392713993500705974424791640227287724705650067537968801074155312570114797832465663858741483400901647799929721470159496987812679821111730689166463366606551267765697921569125290699944304326288818960384200871654827493100325409876812489682711348513244971620081481684340424449568972178318409815746267950146224549923943957635742728889238780346534385817477136072283022902565796081663160648252946167239546424890110821196529528358627773373504225125056523663954597433278174718610370606703664415945161199804631243562222965705129402104600647872785649693343767911111233647766743334611301999675427293224616809442969215988341973159678514604800342052145601875313047852364221840276228543970109429472341439373418554415700439864029182126126555780166736274177582219830001690249143731582595139837209895586321826391814999452798890753335597966118255461143209904547262657727956104064852211561674112309448805185831775145498725414208563477819053457809168792852008698630549450830647801496178703216613708137528937944005515930744164570843474855631165661539606334738839503279229149405656111162420879130403407319921975488206273446734836687100641841717998060185446298997678735552219275033859572628180793848617502491777291673575300297211101525633241431725253827221239047470633458965551885615810334846221083366721155246201486720296861488421251412585452371994052765854956667058152989005149411484243624208727100911576375413403608010677473400955778111396360452775514441825548741754598300817661240268852363212781602854367749994334862150630799392774768527973996929461527098114708300217955057684152676420039296978447817265256411524417754883187887445894130353022388842317869773150647952948848671583706699551985745434110794662277351457044771378507518729537365658152364234398609916864719216448498077322804149512833432154942424273393427629208749974623818973778078002180114151519862694544029256435686883829302646833505994223044918417887864451588047856834236569410763473387053946267508537900833300945851877436680980941544844525786853711677637705576181468642324785126166781221160451843898112783925287679639526886367820669455874656199565561430456794216944922544744491649466852864038501469041752223982614119494425752107037262844982748646605722535227272840737241614295262590818750600682152446698778395840797731822121652655104430172804976277739763346646973261475782149805868676545805017515372016402264906453096545897803426557477555439266024369075314101297725973100535662786670323833137704110282990903782350435888819622487815784902943846410347084957959806691311457091835651974879930411462198631314974388802219688546560811233248145760355918687984846313201786200839700173112807846243294546660463226871823957739032709878892254197891276394543557575946191838680926317472980812747870786530370508495402751983312199142752128770884996983711003898291322931887907171702897478102431849815742495249955783279530071100116870946788229251574041532557327826598269913255656761197623810457653412851472785896979416478595929500127189986637637036604571272745614510419960810914932566459678546613552623592183167012968748532550838681296741202414403822809009633668022825501012148809838864474143686730203083478893084391943797481539519935765574317583241228880915886149481239344051101576686476041869843825807899235712961395473752900914609987610792511497473444033564072045509623215604304751107341738227963259498893539",
        ... (13 lines total) ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer pertains to slow Gradle build speeds **for Windows 10** after you've already gotten the Xmx and Xms memory settings straightened out.

**Windows Defender**

As far as Windows Defender is concerned it's simply not enough to add folders / files to the Windows Defender exclusion list via "Files" or "Folders".

You must add directories pertaining to Android Studio / Gradle / Java (embedded JDK or Oracle JDK) as "**Process**" exclusions to Windows Defender :

- Go through the answer by David Rawson
- During a Gradle build... monitor the Windows Task Manager's Processes
- To Windows Defender, add "Process" exclusions for directories containing the file/executable you see utilizing the CPU during a build associated with Android Studio / Gradle

This obviously comes with security implications.

The following describes more details pertaining to using a "Process" exclusion in Windows Defender (as opposed to adding a simple "File" or "Folder" exclusion) :

> A file name with full path causes the particular binary file to be excluded, i.e. any files it touches, regardless of where the file is located, will not be scanned by Windows Defender. A file name without any path causes any binary file with this file name to be excluded regardless of its location. A path followed by a "*" (e.g. c:\my\private\tools*) causes any binaries under this path to be excluded. Any files touched by these processes will be excluded. This is different from a path exclusion, where files touched by any process under the excluded path is excluded.

The key here being....adding these exclusions as "Process" type exclusions takes into account "files the binary touches" as opposed to manually finding and excluding every file / folder that is generated by Android Studio / Gradle.

**Windows File Indexing**

Windows file indexing seems to also slow down Gradle builds.  Turn off Windows File Indexing for the directories used by Gradle / Android Studio.

Here are my "Windows File Indexing" and "Windows Defender Process" exclusions :

```
 C:\Program Files\Android\*
 C:\Users\<yourUserAcct>\.android\*
 C:\Users\<yourUserAcct>\.AndroidStudio3.0\*
 C:\Users\<yourUserAcct>\.gradle\*
 C:<pathToYourAndroidStudioProjectFolder>
```

Comment: ....got a downvote within minutes of posting this.  Would the downvoter please explain what he doesn't like about this because I just spent a day fine-tuning a brand new Windows machine to build as fast as my 5 year-old macbook.  This was the only thing that got me close to within 10 seconds of my macbook's build speed.

Comment: Yes...the 5 year old macbook still processes full release builds (from a clean) faster than a brand new Windows machine).

Comment: Maybe downvote was because it's not really obvious how to add exceptions even to Windows Defender and even more complicated about indexer. `Windows Defender Security Center` -> `Settings` -> `Virus & treat protection settings` -> `Exclusions`

Comment: @TheGodfather I guess...       ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

It's not compiling that's hurting me here, it's the typing. I could disable all the smart features and be back to notepad++ like [TomTsagk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979161/tomtsagk) suggested in a comment. For today I need more cores and RAM.

Playing devil's advocate I'd argue that typing shouldn't require a 16Gb PC octacore PC. Liked Sajan Rana's advice but things are so slow here it felt mostly a placebo.

To be fair I am using 1.4RC1, which is just short of being in the stable branch. Turning the internet off helped a little. The new feature of simultaneous Design (Preview) and Text views working with XML layouts is very helpful.

No, it is ridiculous. Never leave the stable channel.

Comment: I'm having this EXACT same problem with Android Studio 1.4. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @selbie and jonagon - I too had problems with 1.4 running unusabley slow and eventually found the solution at https://code.google.com/u/110054054823032428814/ It seems that you need to add the line "sun.java2d.d3d=false" to your idea.properties file in the Android Studio executable directory. I've just done that and finally I'm able to work again ...thanks Google for yet more wasted days... :(

Comment: @LairdPleng - That link you provided didn't work, but that solution to set `sun.java2d.d3d=false` might have originated from [the post I made](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191229&q=4k&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). In any case disabling d3d fixed everything.

Comment: @selbie Yes, that was the post I was trying to link to. Don't know how I managed to mess that up! :)

Comment: Try Power Saving Mode, turns off all lint

Answer (score 5):

This might sound stupid and off topic but in my case I was using an external 4k Monitor with my MacBook Pro 13' (MacOS High Sierra, 2016) and I had the resolution set to the wrong scaled resolution. **Switching to another scaled resolution where there was no "using a scaled resolution may affect performance" warning resolved my overall performance issues.** In my case I had to increase the resolution to max.

So for me it was an overall performance problem which first surfaced with Android Studio, it was not an Android Studio specific problem.

**EDIT 25.11.2017**

As a result I had to increase font sizes in Android Studio:

[image]

[image]

and on my Mac in General. I followed some of these [tips](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/increase-text-size-mac) to get that done.

Comment: Well i have the same problem but in all scaled resolutions except the smallest and the biggest one, it says it might effect performance.Does it mean that i have to code in 4k or 1080p =(

Comment: I fear so... I'm using 4k (of course) and had to increase font sizes in Android Studio and on my Mac in general. See edit in post.

Answer (score 4):

In case setting `-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m` (and etc.. mentioned in above answers) doest work, then do this manually:

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (**File > Close Project**).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to **Configure > Settings**.

Step 3 : Go to **Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler**

Step 4 : **Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 1024** and **Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m**.

Step 5 : Close or **Restart Android Studio**.

[image: SOLVED - Andriod Studio 1.3 Gradle Could not reserve enough space for object heap Issue]

Answer (score 3):

Just for anyone looking, after upgrading to El Capitan, I noticed a huge lag with the IDE. After increasing a ton of RAM and using the suggestions above, it turned out that I needed to update the legacy Java, and reinstall via: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

After installing this, all lag was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one thing that worked for me is using physical android device instead of emulator. As in my PC( i5 and 4GB RAM ) the android studio takes about 700MB of memory and the emulator takes another 700. Thus the whole performance of the computer goes down. Working with a physical device saves the strain from the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT EDIT **`studio.vmoptions`** ,It may not work.

In `gradle.properties` file (in app directory) add this :

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx7g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I edited studio.vmoptions, adding the text in BlackBelt's answer (2). Android Studio wouldn't start until I deleted the VMoptions file.

Answer (score 3):

I followed [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb) post and it worked great for me.

EDIT:

Following tips have been mentioned in the above post.

In `gradle.properties`, put this:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

And in build.gradle, put this (Note this will disable lint check):

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I will add some more details in some time

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17986621)

Comment: @Mamun I have added details to the answer. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!
Open `build.gradle` (it's inside your project) and change the both `jcenter` to `mavenCentral`

(you can do it in Global file too: `C:\Program Files\AndroidStudio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root\build.gradle.ftl`  however, you will need to do this modification again after AndroidStudio upgrade)

Comment: Though `mavenCenrtal` is said to be less up-to-date,non-ssl and smaller repository, than `jcenter`

Comment: Thanks, its true, but in those countries with US sanctions upon them, Jcenter refuses to give service, So I think that's why this code works for me.

Answer (score 2):

My Android Studio was not only slow in general use, but also when building.

Here's what I did:

1. Uninstalled Android Studio (Don't delete, uninstall it and check **delete the SDK** too). Then delete Android folders located in C:\Users\\ folder namely: `.android`,  `AndroidStudioX.X`
2. Uninstall the SDKs via the SDK manager, remove everything ( If there is lef SDK folder, delete them )
3. Download and Reinstall the latest build for Android Studio (v2.1.2 as of this writing); Install only the SDK/Emulators you need;

It's fast now.

---

*My Story before that:*

My laptop sports an Intel Core i7-3612QM and 8gig of ram. When I builded, all the 4 cores/8 threads were on 100% usage. My entire system froze until the ~10 minute wass done. Gradle took me like ~10 unproductive minutes of slow down. This is very annoying. I am using Android Studio since 1.4. There were also tremendous slow down when I copy paste code to and from, selecting menus, right-click context menus, editing manifest, editing gradle files, opening layout files, rendering in the UI Editor, etc. Its was very unusable most of the time.

Due to frustration, I did the above steps.  Its fast now. Very usable just as before. I build for only ~20 seconds compare to ~10minutes before that. Also, Android Studio eats about 6gig with emulator and browser with lots of tab open, unlike before its hovering on 98% RAM usage. Not just that, I even saved 45 gigs of space for whatever reason. I only use couple of SDKs and Emulators when I checked the Android SDK folder, it occupies 45gig of space! I think the IDE is having a hard time accessing/IO on my SDK folder.

If you've tried other given solutions and still experiencing the same issue, it may be time to remove Android IDE/SDKs altogether and start anew (it might take you sometime to setup that newly, but its worth it. Considering I've been suffering this sluggishness for months and cost me my productivity).

I really guess that this might be caused by cumulative patches that has been done since then. Or the 45 gig SDK folder on my poorly defragmented drive. I don't know and I could be wrong.

Thank you! HTH

Answer (score 2):

I just want to share my case:

1. if you need play-store library, don't compile all of it, just compile library that you need. example: if you only need maps library instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'` do this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'` on your gradle
2. Dont use OpenJDK for the java, I use java 7 oracle and it works well. if yout need to change default java do this on linux terminal `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and pick the number

I'm using ubuntu 32bit 4GB RAM. that's all the issue I ever encounter with AS.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to speed up **Android Studio.**

- **Speed up gradle build time.**

  1.Go to Project gradle.properties file and remove comment from both line.

  2.copy gradle.properties file to your .gradle folder so that you don't need to setup for every project.
- **Enable Work Offline** so that Android studio/Gradle don't need to check for newer file over internet every time.

[image: Go to Project gradle.properties file and remove comment from both line]

Answer (score 2):

- I should mention that if you are using **Mac**, downloading and running an app from the App Store (like "iBoostUp" etc.)  which will clean out unused system files can speed up your computer dramatically, including AS.
- I also found that adding more **memory** to my Mac sped up AS as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've quickly resolved this issue by upgrading gradle (Android Studio seems to use old version).

1) Download latest version (https://gradle.org/gradle-download/) and unpack somewhere.
 
2) Update `path` in Android Studio: `File > Settings > Build, Ex../Gradle`

Answer (score 1):

Click `Help > Edit Custom properties` and add this line:

```
sun.java2d.noddraw=false
```

... worked successfully for me to fix the speed issues (Windows 10 64-bit). It's absolute voodoo as far as I'm concerned (I haven't done any research on why that should work), and there is a warning above that property that it can cause blinking and fail to repaint on some graphics cards, but there you go. (Inspired by LairdPleng's comment, further information)

Comment: Looks similar to abysmal performance in browsers with hardware rendering enabled on laptops with intel graphics and no dedicated gpu.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that AS transfers too much data from/to HDD. It is very annoying, especially when starting to write a new line of code. So, I think, better will be reinstalling a hard disk with SSD. I have i5 with 6 Gb of memory, and the CPU seldom loads more than 50% even at build time. So, the most weak place is HDD.

Answer (score 1):

### 1 The most common cause of slowness is using Emulator

, especially more than one. USB debugging with the external mobile device can be used.

### 2 Invalidate caches every month or so

One Simple thing that no one has mentioned is File>Invalidate Caches.

[image: Invalidate Caches Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Please add in `setting.gradle` (root folder)

```
startParameter.offline=true
```

Comment: Isn't this same as checking `offline` (like suggested in above answers)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to measure speed of Android Studio 3.1.4 on the same hardware: Macbook Pro 2011, RAM 4Gb, SSD 240GB Samsung, Core i5 2.4Ghz. I have installed on this machine 3 different OS: Windows 10, MacOS Hight Sierra 10.13, Ubuntu 18.04. Avarage build time (running command: gradlew clean build, gradlew clean assembleRelease) on MacOS/Ubuntu was around 30% faster than on Windows.

On my another working machine: Core i5 3.0 Ghz 7400, RAM 16Gb, SSD 250Gb. Build time takes 4.34min on Windows 10 machine. The same project on a little bit slower processor, but with the same RAM and SSD and it is running Ubuntu 16.04 build time takes two times faster!! Well I was shocked with results, but still I choose Windows as development machine, because it's much more comfortable for me to use comfortable and usable keyboard and sotfware than on Unix like systems. And even if I had to choose between MacOS and Ubuntu - mac is really much easier to setup everything, and Ubuntu is too complex to use for usual people. Choise is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from following the optimizations mentioned in existing answers (not much helpful, was still painfully slow), doing below did the trick for me.

HP Notebook with 6 GM RAM and i5 processor I have, still android studio was terribly slow.
After checking task manager for memory usage, noticed that there is a software called "HP Touchpoint Analytics Client" that was taking more than 1 GB memory.
Found that it's a spyware installed by HP in Windows 10 after searching about it in Google.

Uninstalled a bunch of HP software which does nothing and slows down the system. 
Now, Android studio is considerably fast - Gradle build completes in less than 30 seconds when compared to more than 2 minutes before. Every keystroke would take 5 seconds to respond, now it is real time and performance is comparable with Eclipse.

This might be true for Laptops from other vendors as well like Dell, etc.
HP really messed up the user experience with their spyware for Windows 10 users. 
Uninstall them, it will help Android studio and improves the overall laptop experience as well.

Hope this helps someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Balance memory consumption and build speed using gradle options. For sample

Android Studio 2022.1.1 (PC RAM 16GB)

Gradle v7.3.3 (./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)

AGP v7.2.0 (./build.gradle)

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0
```

Cache Fix Gradle Plugin

```
org.gradle.android.cache-fix:org.gradle.android.cache-fix.gradle.plugin:2.5.3
```

This Google Services dependency version supports Gradle Configuration Cache

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5
```

./gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.jetifier.ignorelist=bcprov-jdk15on
android.useAndroidX=true
kapt.incremental.apt=true
kapt.use.worker.api=true
kotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xms1g -Xmx4g
manifestmerger.enabled=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:InitialHeapSize=1g -XX:MaxHeapSize=6g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g -XX:NewSize=1g -XX:MaxNewSize=2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache-problems=warn
```

Useful links:

https://proandroiddev.com/how-we-reduced-our-gradle-build-times-by-over-80-51f2b6d6b05b

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/profile-your-build#using-the-gradle---profile-option

Comment: What is this? What are you trying to say man ?
List out the steps to solve this problem, at least.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case where Android Studio **may be slow if you cross more than, say 5000 lines of code in a single class**. The IDE seems to be facing issues in loading / formatting / linting.

Modularizing the class / XML files has helped in my case. Create a class / Utility class and have the logic there, or follow MVVM kind of code.

At the last resort, **try Power Saving Mode**, from File->Power Save Mode.

Comment: Of course my app is more than 5000 lines of code.

Comment: You can turn on Power Saving mode, and try to reduce the code in a single class, split it as functions and keep logic in separate class. You can follow MVP or MVVM for better organisation of code. The key thing was to reduce number of lines in single file. Then turn off power saving mode.