# Android Studio compile error : enum constant INSTANT_RUN_REPLACEMENT does not exist in class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting following error in my project with Android Studio 2.0 preview 5 and gradle plugin 1.5.0. Even clean project throws the same error.

> EtaskArtifacts.bin .gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin). > rror:Could not read entry ':app:processDebugManifest' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (/PROJECT_PATH/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin).
>   enum constant INSTANT_RUN_REPLACEMENT does not exist in class com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$Invoker$Feature

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Edit : The issue is already fixed, please upgrade to latest version of Android Studio, you can track the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198957).

I found a simple solution. Just delete `ProjectDirectory/.gradle/taskArtifacts.bin` file and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks it saved my time. can you please explain how this solution work

Comment: Your `taskArtifacts.bin` files gets corrupted while moving from gradle plugin 2.0.0-aplha5 to 1.5.0. So just delete it :)

Comment: Or just delete all subdirectories under `.gradle/` dir, and rebuild the project.  No need to restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 14):

Here are the steps for fixing this

1. Go to your `Run/Debug configuration`
2. Select `Edit Configuration...`.
3. On General tab you might be getting red warning to `Update Project`.
4. Click on it, it will handle handle rest.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Just go to your `workbench` directory. Navigate to your `ProjectFolder` and then `delete` the `.gradle` folder. 
Then rebuild your project!**

Answer (score 2):

Open `terminal` and run this line code to solve this problem:

```
rm .gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This morning i had the same problem. The steps that worked for me are:

- "Invalidate Cache and Restart" on Android Studio.
- Click on "Run app"
- Android Studio show you a dialog to update gradle

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Open your_app/build.gradle file, and modify the compile dependecy in my case com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3 was changed by com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5

[my_app/build.gradle not module my_app/app/build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejanz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Switching to gradle 2.0.0-alpha5 would probably fix that but in my case that causes build times of over 30 minutes and other significant issues.

Comment: Are you aware there is also alpha6?

Comment: @gbhall AS only offers me alpha5 with preview-5. Setting it manually installed it but still had the same issues. Switching back to gradle plugin 2.8 and 1.3.1 helped some but not as  much as i was hoping, definitely nowhere near the compile times i had prior to this mess starting up.

Comment: I had to switch back to alpha3 too. Currently helping Google with another bug report I have.

Comment: try some of the suggestions in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-too-slow they helped with AS 1.5.1 gradle 2.8, 1.3.1  as it brought 18min compile time down to 3min. Going to try that tomorrow with preview-5 and the latest alpha. Also enabled offline setting for gradle before i forget. Oh and it also made the UI usable again.