# Android studio Project will be fast on SSD?

Tags: android, performance, gradle

I'm running my Android Studio on my

> ```
> sony vaio 
> AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) HD graphics 1.65 ghz
> and 8 gb Ram
> ```

and is installed on HDD(not that good) but the android studio is very slow and gradle build took about 5 min until the project runs and sometimes gradle build  repeats another time 
this is really a catastrophy!! so what is the problem in my computer? 
and if I replace my HDD by SSD will that be good and android studio will run just in few seconds ! help me please and thanks in advance :)

Comment: aside from SSD, try the suggestions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-too-slow

Answer (score 3):

Replacing drive won't help much as the problem lies within gradle build process which takes huge time to rebuild project every time you run it.

Here is the link to update your gradle settings for faster build processing  :

https://medium.com/@101/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed#.x2w5e5efk

***In case link is dead, here are some steps to speed up your gradle process:***

**Step 1: Update Gradle version**

- An easier way to accomplish this is to go to: Open Module Settings (your project) > Project Structure
- In Gradle version and enter 2.10
- Download Gradle Release distributive from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

**NOTE**:You should use updated gradle version for above two steps

- Copy above file to **AndroidStudio/gradle** folder
- Last step is to add your distribution in Android Studio Settings > Gradle (Use local gradle distribution and set it to above pasted zip file)

**Step 2: Enable Offline mode, Gradle daemon and parallel build for the project**

- Go to *Gradle* from android studio *Setting* and click in *Offline* work box.
- Go to *Compiler* from android studio *Setting* and add `“— offline”` in command-line box and click Compile independent modules in parallel.

**Step 3: The next step is to enable the Gradle daemon and parallel build for your project**

- Add following lines to gradle.properties file:

  org.gradle.parallel=true

  org.gradle.daemon=true
- Increase the max heap size in case you have a large project (gradle.properties file):

**org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

**Step 4: Tweek Memory settings**

- In your module’s build file, add:

  dexOptions {

  ```
  jumboMode = true

  javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  ```

  }

Here 4g is 4 GB of memory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Creating link only answers is bad practice. The site you reference could be deleted or modified anytime which could make your answer useless or even wrong. You for sure should link the original article, but you also have to include all necessary information to solve the problem with the answer itself.

Comment: @t.niese I wasn't even thinking of posting it as an answer. I was missing enough reputation to comment, that's why i posted this link as an answer. BTW thanks for reminding that i should add all the info. myself to keep the answer long lived. Edited the answer.