# Android Studio makes Windows 10 crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using **Android Studio** for a few months without any hiccups but now it keeps using too much computer resources resulting to system crash and sometimes blue screen of death. The usage of **CPU** and **RAM** goes up to 100% when **gradle** is running and crashes every time I try to use emulator. When I type the code the program works fine. My **Android Studio version is 2.2** right now. Any solution?

Comment: check solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-too-slow

Comment: I've tried many of solutions answered there. No change. Also I changed Android emulator to Genymotion and now it loads it but when I try to build app, system crashes.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the line with MaxPermSize in your gradle.property?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any change.