# Instant Run is disabled when Jack compiler is used

Tags: android, android-instant-run, android-jack-and-jill

I got this message in `gradle` :

```
Instant Run is disabled when Jack compiler is used
```

my compile time is taken too long .

```
3:54:11 PM Gradle build finished with 1 warnings(s) in 17m 15s 937ms
```

I think it because this message.

I'm worikng as offline mode .

my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*.*.*"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/felipecsl/m2repository/master' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.carlonzo.stikkyheader:core:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:foldable-layout:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:android-commons:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.FuckBoilerplate:RxPaparazzo:0.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
}
```

Comment: Instant Run does not currently work with Jack and will be disabled while using the new toolchain

Answer (score 7):

That a known issue. As reported [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#known-issues)

> Instant Run does not currently work with Jack and will be disabled
>   while using the new toolchain

Check my answer here [AndroidStudio is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-too-slow) to see if you can spee d up the building time

Answer (score 6):

Instant Run does not currently work with Jack.

See docs:
https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html