# Failed to create JVM; JVM path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre

Tags: java, android, jvm

When I start Android Studio I am facing this error.

[image: Error Launching Android Studio]

It was working properly until today. But Today I searched for speeding up Android Studio and applying 2nd option of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up) solution and after that android studio starts throwing this error. I searched a lot but couldn't find the proper solution. I also check JAVA_HOME path and my JDK is also 64 bit. Even I also tried by reinstall android studio again but the error continues.

I am using windows 10, 64 bit Operating System.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Finally, I have to [RESET](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/reset-windows-10-pc) my PC, and it is the only solution I am able to start Android Studio start successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same error, shortly after selecting `Help > Edit Custom JVM Options` from my Android Studio menu. Soon as I did that, I wasn't able to restart into my Android studio, citing above error. I tried many options suggested all over, setting `JAVA_HOME` and whatnot but none worked.

What finally worked was going to `<HOME FOLDER>/.AndroidStudio2.2/` and deleting the file `studio64`. For Windows users the file should be `studio64.exe` (see below). Please note my Android studio version at the time of writing was `2.2.3`, so the Folder/directory to navigate to was based on the major version i.e `2.2`. Depending on your Android studio version, the directory to find the file above may be different. Hope this saves someoene some valuable time.

For windows PC:

- Add jdk location to system environments as `JAVA_HOME`
- Delete file from location: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudio2.3\studio64.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But I didn't find the `C:\Users\usеrname\.AndroidStudio` folder. Then I looked in the `C:\Users\usеrname` folder and found the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file.

After deleting this file, Android Studio started without errors.

Comment: File location: "c:\Users\Mavlonbek\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\studio64.exe.vmoptions"

Comment: Your comment worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Now I tried all but this didn't work, what did work was that I went to my environment variable looks for JAVA_HOME and I added the path
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre

Answer (score 1):

For 2020 version, instead of C:\Users\usеrname.AndroidStudio folder, check C:\Users*Computer Name*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve this problem. It's so simple guys, you have only to delete this file `studio64.exe.vmoption`

You can find it here `C:\Users\yourPcname\.AndroidStudio2.3`

I hope that was helpful

Comment: that works fine; in Android Studio 3.5 version that file is located at:
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.AndroidStudio3.5\config

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find the file **studio64.exe.vmoptions** in "*C:\Users"username"\ .AndroidStudio2.3*"

then it will be in this directory
"*C:\program files\android\android studio\bin*"

It works for me