# Is there anyway to boost Android Studio's start up speed?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

It currently takes me around 10 minutes to boot up android studio if I don't open it the moment I start my computer. I am currently using an i7 with 16gb ram so I don't quite understand why it is so slow.

Comment: Maybe the virus checker? Add the directories to excluded directory

Comment: I don't think this is a question for SO but...maybe you're system is cooked? or the hard drive is dying? how much cracked software do you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up