# It lags when i am using android studio

Tags: performance, android-studio, lag

my laptop is i7 4510U , 4GB ram , Intel HD graphics 2gb , Nvidia GeForce 840m 4GB
why it's so laggy when Iam using android studio?

Comment: It's not a programming question. You should read SO rules.

Comment: The answer to virtually all PC performance problems is more RAM, and last but *certainly* not least use an SSD instead of a hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

Your 4GB of ram is to blame,

to use well Android Studio, you need at least 8GB of RAM (more if intend to use emulators), just note that the GPU have no use here, and even the processor you just need a mid range processor to work well, but when compiling the more powerful processor you have the better.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems but then i disabled some plugins and tried to build gradle offline, you can find detailed answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up