# Android Studio is blank after modifying configurations

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to speed up Android Studio by following some of the suggestions made in:

[Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

Specifically, I changed `build process heap size` to 1021 and added `-Xmx512m` to the `additional build process VM options`. I restarted Android Studio and now am presented with this:

[image]

The screen gets stuck like this and doesn't change.

I have deleted the old Android studio installation and downloaded and Installed a new Android studio with no luck.

Comment: I see someone is on a downvoting spree.How exactly is this a bad question?

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, here is what I exactly did, I solved it by removing android studio with help of an uninstaller (iobit uninstaller actually) then I installed a new version of android studio in diffrent location/folder

Comment: This is exactly what I did at first