# Android Studio takes too long to launch or open

Tags: android-studio

When I run Android Studio it takes too long to open. Approximately 30 minutes.

I have an i5 processor with 4 GB ram & 1 TB and run Android Studio version 2.2.3

[image: screenshot]

I have tried many different versions but none of them are working properly, not one has ever opened.

Help me out with this. Tell me what I should do so that Android Studio will run a little bit faster!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

Comment: Did you try to start it through command line and see if there are any errors/warnings ?

Comment: no, i didnt try this out using command line ....can you please guide me how can i check it ??

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the steps you applied during installation.

I'll suggest you use your command prompt window to check your jdk version. Run your command prompt terminal and type : java - version 
Notice the build. If youy build is less than version 7, you would need to download the latest java jdk from the official site.

Hence you would need uninstall your android studio, upgrade your jdk, then re-install the  android studio.