# How to solve this fatal exception on Android Studio: Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, jvm, 64-bit

I was tweaking Android Studio to make it fast. Upon suggestion from this post-
[Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up) I made the below changes:
Under Help> Edit Custom VM Options I have:

```
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Now Android Studio wont start. The error shows up as-

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most
>   of your RAM Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A
>   fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Any suggestion to solve this error or any commands to reset Android Studio or revert this. I tried to edit the Vmoptions but it doesnt had any effect.

Comment: Have you also wrote `# <------ increase this to most of your RAM ` ?? Remove this sentense

Comment: 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I couldn't find this sentence @Upendra in the studio.vmoptions file

Comment: 64bit @Sahdeep..

Comment: What is your ram size?

Comment: My system is of 4Gb ram and 64 bit Ubuntu 18 beta

Comment: You are *miss-reading* the quote. The error says you have used most of your RAM and that is an **ERROR**. The JVM has a default setting of 1/4 of main memory (for Max heap size). If you have `4 GB` it will default to `1 GB`. I would never go above `2 GB`. You can set it for **all** java based tools using the `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2048m` *environmental variable*.

Comment: will a java re-install solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Find your `Android Studio bin` directory.

In windows the `bin` directory for Android Studio is usually:

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

Android Studio menu:

**Help> Edit Custom VM Options** changes a **file** with a name of the *form* like:
`studio.vmoptions`

It may be called:

- `studio.vmoptions`
- `studio.exe.vmoptions`
- `studio64.exe.vmoptions`

**Note** that on `Linux` machines this file may be named `studio64.vmoptions`

**Fix** *this/these* files and you should be back to a *usable* `Android Studio`.

Comment: I checked the `idea64.vmoption` and `idea.vmoption` files in my `idea-IU-181.5281.24/bin` folder but the file is set to default. I'm still getting the error. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?