# Emulator from Android Studio starts "thinking" every few seconds and doesn't let me debug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever I'm debugging an app using an emulator from Android Studio (clicking Debug 'app') the system shows the mouse arrow with a spinning wheel. It is very difficult to write anything, the context menu dissapears before I'm able to click...not only annoying but impossible to debug properly. Even for writing this question I had to stop the emulator.

I have tried 2 different apps (one of them a very basic tutorial so that there are no errors in the code), just with the emulator on with no app charged, with 2 different Virtual Devices( Nexus 5X API 27 and Nexus S API 22) with the same result.

Android Studio Version 3.1.2

How can I make this stop happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to the 6th response to [Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up?rq=1)

> An anti-virus is causing the slow-down
>
> To solve this, you will have to add the correct directories to the
>   "excluded folders" of your anti-virus. Assume that your Windows
>   username is "Username" and you have installed Android Studio on C:
>   drive. You would then request to exclude from the virus check the
>   following directories:

```
C:\Users\Username\.android
C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio2.2
C:\Users\Username\.gradle
C:\Users\Username\.m2
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Extended details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951063/2729605