# Android studio slows down

Tags: android, android-studio

I have one annoying issue and I wonder what is behind it.

After working with layouts and resources in Android Studio (all 3+ version), I see significant slow down and I must restart and invalidate caches to get default smooth usage.

Studio gets so slow, that I cannot write text, scroll, or do anything without seeing a delay of 1-2 seconds.

This shows up much faster if I work with complex layouts and bigger resource files (strings, dimens, styles etc).

Any idea or we are stuck until IntelliJ improves it?

Comment: what are your system specifications?

Comment: MacBook Pro, mid 2015, i7, 16GB, 256SSD. Maybe something is related to MacOS ?

Comment: have you tried solutions from this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

1. Go to msconfig and turn off unnecessary applications in start up tab.
2. When you run an android emulator, turn on Use Host GPU option particularly if you have a powerful graphic card.

**Reduce Build Process Heap Size in Android Studio**

3. Go to File->other settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler
4. Change the build process heap size to smaller amount like 512MB from default size of 700MB.

**Reduce DEX compiler Heap Size**

5. File->other settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Android compiler
6. Maximum Heap size by changing the default value of 700MB to a lower value like 400MB.
7. Disabling VCS in android studio and using an external program to handle VCS helped a lot. You can disable VCS by going to File->Settings->Plugins and disable the following:

•   CVS Integration

•   Git Integration

•   GitHub

•   Google Cloud Testing

•   Google Cloud Tools Core

•   Google Cloud Tools for Android Studio

•   hg4idea

•   Subversion Integration

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some methods I have employed to address slowdown issues in Android Studio:**

**1.Update to the Latest Version:**
Ensure that you are using the latest version of Android Studio. Regular updates often include performance improvements and bug fixes that can contribute to a smoother experience.

**2.Utilize the Latest Theme:**
Opt for the latest theme available in Android Studio. The latest themes are designed for optimal performance, providing a smoother and more efficient user interface.

**3.Optimize Android Emulator Settings:**
When using the Android emulator, choose a device with medium settings rather than high-end devices. High-end devices tend to consume more RAM, potentially causing slowdowns in performance.

**4.Regular Device Maintenance:**
Periodically delete and reinstall a new emulator device every 4-5 days. This practice helps in maintaining a clean and optimized environment, contributing to improved performance.

**5.Proper Shutdown Procedure:**
When concluding work in Android Studio, avoid directly closing the IDE. Instead, close all open tabs, exit from the Android Studio interface on your computer, use the terminal to issue a quit command, and then stop the emulator. This systematic approach can prevent potential issues and ensure a more stable environment.

By incorporating these practices, I have experienced significant improvements in the performance of Android Studio. I hope implementing these suggestions proves beneficial for you as well. **Have a great day!**