# Couldn't launch android studio on Ubuntu 18.4 LTS Error: Could not find or load main class Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

Tags: android-studio

I have followed the steps [here] ([Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)) in order to try and make my android studio faster.
after doing so android studio won't even launch .

I have tried the command ./studio.sh from the terminal but I am getting this

> error: Error: Could not find or load main class Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by:

going to dir home/username/AndroidStudiox.x/config/studio.vmoptions
I had added a couple of lines there before
I edited the file and deleted it's contents. and I was able to launch android studio again