# How can I make Android studio run faster without killing its functionalities

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

How can I make Android studio run faster on my PC
Especially the gradle build process.
Also why are there no much information online about the Android Jetpack Compose ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

Comment: This is a question being asked since 2015. There's been upgrade and the answers are not solving my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find many ways of doing that by a simple google search.

These articles/posts could be helpful:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-speed-up-android-studio/
- https://medium.com/android-news/is-your-android-studio-always-slow-heres-how-to-speed-up-immediately-326ef9238024
- [Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)