# How are gradle projects different from , Normal android studio projects

Tags: android

How are gradle projects different from , Normal android studio projects

Comment: Please attach the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, Just uploaded Image

Comment: Please include system information, Android Studio version information

Comment: How Do I get That Info?
I downloaded everything 4 days ago , So It should be latest.

Comment: run `systeminfo` in `cmd`. is the android studio version latest??

Comment: Yes It's latest. BTW Thank you alot for putting so much time init. If I were a millionaire I would have given you a million ^^ Image is attached to main post of my system info.

Comment: check if you have the latest version of jdk or download it from http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u66-b17/jdk-8u66-windows-i586.exe
also try uninstalling and re-installing android studio

Comment: Its latest M sure, also yr link doesnt work since it requires me to accept licence agreement tht is suppose to be on previous page, which i dont have, 
If possible I would like to avoid reinstalling android coz its a pain, takes like 5 hours. to set everything up.
Anyways, thnx a bunch for all yr help.

Comment: What happens when you close and reopen android studio? Could just be a one time thing. Also a stretch, but maybe it's a graphics drivers problem.

Comment: @Ain786 try this- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Probably you won't be able to do anything useful with Android Studio and only 1.5 GB of RAM. The white screen might be caused by the lack of RAM. So buy some more or have a look at [reducing Andoid Studio's memory consumption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory).

Comment: OK, I tried the things and disabled the things they tole me to disable in that post but to no avail,
Now just last question before I uninstall AS and get replace it with eclipse.

I can run projects in gradle, How are gradle projects different from normal Android Studios projects?