# android studio showing error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at  
https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

Comment: restart AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Omar said, the usual procedure is to clear any traces of cache on Android Studio.

Can be done with : `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Additionally, you can increase gradle's JVM memory. I noticed a huge leap in performance when I did this for the first time on my main development machine (which has a rough 16gb of RAM)
Just uncomment the line your **gradle.properties** file and alter the values to your liking.

```
\# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Regards

Comment: Acctually the i copied this project from my laptop(8gb ram) to pc(2gb ram) and i have allocated more memory for android studio in my laptop so it may be the problem

Comment: please can you give me solution

Comment: Perhaps that is the problem! 
From gradle's page : "The solution to this problem is the Gradle Daemon: a long-lived background process that executes your builds much more quickly than would otherwise be the case. We accomplish this by avoiding the expensive bootstrapping process as well as leveraging caching, by keeping data about your project in memory."
Android Studio uses by itself a huge chunk of memory (the average is 1.5gb). Since gradle bulks everything into memory in order to deploy faster runs, it may be draining what remains of your memory and eventually crashing due to low memory.

Comment: You can follow this other [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory).

I have a 8gb machine and with my casual build with gradle I reach up to 3.5/4.0GB of used RAM.
Like it is commonly suggested, you can upgrade your RAM to improve the JVM performance.
Try to run your project and at the same time inspect the Task Manager for CPU and RAM load. If it reaches values above 90%, lack of resources is clearly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest invalidating Android Studio caches through going to `File`->`Invalidate Caches/Restart`