# Suggestions to Smoothly run Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner to Android Programming. Previously I used eclipse to create apps. Now I want to install Android Studio on my computer. Please suggest what I will do to smoothly run Android Studio.

[My computer's configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHhr.png)

Comment: Far more powerful machines than yours have failed miserably. Do a little searching, there is already a question with multiple answers on how to improve android studio experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio takes too much memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory)