# Android Studio 2.2.3 hangs a lot in my laptop

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a HP laptop with 4GB RAM and core i5 processor. In android studio download page it has been specified that 4GB RAM is recommended. But still my Android Studio hangs and takes a lot of time to respond.

Comment: `2.3` is the latest. Not 2.2.3

Comment: Have similar problem after a while error pops up cand find gradle 2.3. Did not have a chance to look into it. I have 8 gig

Comment: @MotKohn Latest build tools require Gradle 3.3 or higher

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html it says 8 GB RAM recommended.

Comment: The recommendation is 8 GB.  Gradle uses a lot of ram. I sometimes use it on a minimum requirement system and it is quite a pain despite tweaking HEAP-MAX for both gradle and android-studio itself.

Comment: Latest or old version is not my point. How can I make it work more efficiently?@cricket_007

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30450007/451600 for tweaking the allowances for different parts of AS.

Comment: I have asked same question before and it's an off topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455092/how-to-reduce-memory-when-running-android-studio.
Android Studio is heavy. Try disable some plugin would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here are some Tips to speed Up Android Studio**

- Update Android Studio([2.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)) and Java To the latest One
- Disable unwanted **Plugins**. [Demo Video](https://youtu.be/nqKduJF4GNo)
- If you are not using VCS and Google Cloud Services then disable the following Plugins:

> GitIntegration, GitHub, CVS Integration, Google Login and its
>   dependent Plugins, Subversion Integration.

- Close All Windows and Browser While Using Android Studio.
- Avoid Built in **Emulators**. Try  [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or Real Devices(Recommended)
- Disable Unwanted **Startup Programs**. [Check the help here](https://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/)
- Tweak the Gradle to [reduce Build Time](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/10-tips-to-improve-your-gradle-build-time-1ddeca924759#.spj2thrn9)
- Update Your RAM to **8GB** (atleast 4GB)

Hope its helpful..!! Happy Androidify...!!!!

Answer (score 6):

For memory, Android Studio says this

> 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator

---

Your OS takes maybe 1-2 GB of RAM itself.

You have a web browser open? That takes some RAM

Open up Android Studio, and it is starved of memory. Running the emulator would be out of the question.

---

**tl;dr** Buy a RAM upgrade [or play around with JVM settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory/30450007#30450007).

Comment: They have a guide for low memory systems.  So you don't have to wait for the ram upgrade to ship.  https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#low_memory