# Android Studio get stuck when typing

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am using AS 3.1.2 to create an app but when I typing code, which is always, the AS have a delay from letter to letter and it very annoying to work like this.
I treid to reinstall the AS but it didn't work.

Someone maby know how to fix it?
I have 16gb ram
and Intel I5 6500 processor

When the AS running he using +- 2.5gb of ram

[image]

Comment: I have the same setup, same ram usage and same issue. I guess downgrading is the best option, unless you need the new features.

Comment: 0
down vote

What is the usage of your resources (RAM and CPU percentage)? If another program is using most of your resources that might be the reason

Comment: I added an image.
As you can see I am not using all of my ram.

Comment: This only starts happening to me in the layout editor. It started happening when they added the blueprint mode...

Comment: 1st you want to click on **AS** and then Click on **End tast** after that right click on AS and click on **Run as administrator**. 
2nd step you want to go on Settings and select Offline mode 
try this it's work or not tell me :) *Hope it's helpful for you* @user5327287

Comment: Here is a topic that might help you <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176353/android-studio-takes-too-much-memory>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the actual cause, it's merely a proposition. Have you tried checking the compatibility of AS3 with your Windows version, because from your task Manager view, it is evident that you have a 32 bit system. Since AS 3 is released recently with 32 bit compatibility being dropped with recently released softwares, games and OS, I assume the problem is with your 32 bit system. Try running it on a 64 bit system and it may solve the problem.

Comment: I hava windows 10 pro 64bit and I am using the 64bit AS

Comment: And you have the same specs ?...16 GB RAM and i5 processor ?